# How to support 20 feet of 4 inch pvc drain pipe horizontally along a concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, pipe, drainage, anchor, support

I need to run 20 feet of 4 inch drain pipe horizontally along a concrete wall. Someone suggested saddle clamps and anchors. I am not sure exactly what type to use, especially if the pipe is full of rain water.

Comment: I think we can safely assume that the word was used to differentiate from a vertical section. It's a useful descriptive hint with no obvious alternative.

Comment: If a tiny bit tilted so it drains, that may reduce mosquito problems.

Answer (score 6):

Any of the pipe hangers available at your local big-box home improvement store are designed to support a *full* pipe. They would be just decorations if they didn't...

Pick a type that seems simplest to you to use, get appropriate fasteners (you're attaching this to concrete, a simple screw or nail isn't going to do the trick), ensure you've got the proper 1/4" per foot of run slope (i.e. the drain end needs to be 5" lower than the input end after 20') and have at.

You can use J-hooks, saddle clamps, or just about anything else designed for the purpose.

Comment: Pipe hanger strap is another method, if "cost effective but relatively ugly" is OK in the application.

Comment: Very true, @Ecnerwal. I'd go with a few extra hangars if using just strapping, but that's me...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a robust solution, sprinkler pipe hangers with hex bolts would do well. You could install simple angle brackets on the wall (with the horizontal portion at the top) and drill for these. This would also give you some degree of adjustment in case your brackets weren't exactly positioned.

[image]